# Align labels on opposite sides of Highcharts container (donut graph)

Tags: highcharts

I have a project using `Highcharts 5` . I'm trying to get the chart labels on opposite sides of the donut graph, aligned straight left and straight right on each side, with the connectors spanning the distance appropriately.

Attached is the comp of what it should look like. Any thoughts on how to achieve this?

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create the legend manually (html label and connector line with dot) using `renderer`:

```
    var points = this.series[0].points,
      renderer = this.renderer;

    points.forEach(function(point) {
      var labelOptions = point.options.label;
      if (labelOptions) {

        // text
        renderer.text(labelOptions.text, labelOptions.x, labelOptions.y - 30, true).add();

        // connector
        var path = ['M', labelOptions.x, labelOptions.y].concat(labelOptions.connector.path);
        renderer.path(path).attr({
          stroke: 'gray',
          'stroke-width': 1,
        }).add();

        // dot
        renderer.circle(labelOptions.x, labelOptions.y, 3).attr({
          fill: 'gray',
          'stroke-width': 1,
        }).add();

      }
    });
```

**Options:**

```
{
  name: 'Microsoft Internet Explorer',
  y: 56.33,
  label: {
    x: 400,
    y: 100,
    connector: {
      path: ['l', -50, 0, 'l', 0, 100]
    },
    text: "<div class='label'><img src='https://wordpress.highcharts.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/28160952/highcharts_logo.png' width='30' height='30'></img><div>Label text in HTML</div></div>"
  }
}
```

**Live working example** (one label created)**:** http://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/wdtpyof1/

This demo is only a good starting point. You should create your own mechanisms responsible for positioning labels.

**API reference:** http://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

This is solution for your issue 
you can customize the connectors and get the chart labels on opposite sides of the donut graph.

http://jsfiddle.net/nmtri1101/ogfbxfqd/2/

```
Code jsfiddle :)
```